# "Not responding" error while CPU and Memory are free

Tags: windows, memory, cpu, task-manager, real-time

Sometimes, while CPU and Physical memory are free, some program's status change to **Not responding**! Why?!

For example as you see below, **80% of CPU** and **25% of RAM** are **free**! but VMware went to **Not Responding**. Why it doesn't use this free CPU and RAM?

[image]

I was guessed that the Operation-Sysyem restrict every program and allocate a maximum CPU and RAM to each program, so I change the priority of process of this program (vmware.exe) to **Real-Time**! but the problem is still remain. Why?

FYI : I change the priority by do a right click on name of the process in the process tab of `Windows-Task-Manager` and select `Set Priority` and ...

Comment: I would guess that the program had a problem.

Comment: @cliff2310 This is not only for VMware! I also had this problem with other programs sometimes. It remains for 10 second or less!

Comment: Well, it could be a hardware problem, like a disk that is giving errors on read or write tries.  Check the error logs. Or it could be waiting on some other hardware to respond to a request.

Comment: Analyze Wait Chain of Vmware ad look why it hangs: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht074911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "not responding" error from the OS just means that the program is not responding to the requests from the OS in a timely fashion. Memory/processor usage is only one of the reasons for programs to slow down stop responding. A program can crash because of any other error within that specific program (vmware or any other).

Comment: What kind of error?